# Alfine 11 chain guard

Tags: chain, chainring, internally-geared-hub, shopping

I'm planning to invest into a Alfine 11 set (both hub gear and crank+front cog(45)).
I'm also looking for solution for chain guard for Alfine cog for commuting. I've found Curana brand that makes good chain guards for Alfine (C-Lite that makes possible to use original Alfine ring and chain guard together), although I'm not able to find online dealer to buy one.

Would you recommend any online store to buy Curana stuff?
If it is not possible, would you recommend other good chain guard for Alfine?

Comment: In a lot of cases, if you want a particular one piece of bicycle equipment, your LBS can probably order it for you. Or you can email the company and/or its distributor in your country.

Comment: Unfortunatelly they haven't got distributor in my country. I thought I should order from them directly although they say in their catalog that they accept minimum 200 piece order.

Comment: I think any chainguard designed for a single front chainwheel with a single rear cog should work for you. That is to say, most any standard aftermarket chainguard should work for you.

Comment: OK, I thought that I going to get some concrete tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution was **HEBIE Chainbar 394**. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought a bike with an Alfine 8 transmission. I plan to add a [Chain Glider](http://www.hebie.de/index.php?id=67&L=1). It will mean changing the front chain ring to one of the supported sizes, so I will buy the Chain Glider, a Surly chainring and new rear sprocket from [SJS Cycles](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/hebie-shophebie_pg1/) on the basis of [this thread](http://www.thorncycles.co.uk/forums/index.php?topic=4412.msg35315#msg35315). [Here](http://www.thorncycles.co.uk/forums/index.php?topic=2233.0;wap2) and [here](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/accessories/product/review-hebie-chainglider-33772/) are some positive reviews.

Comment: Yes, I know Chain Glider. The only problem is that Alfine front cog has 45 teeth, there's no option for that with Chain Glider

Comment: That's why I will change from a 39 to 38 front chain ring, and as a side benefit, get a better setup for the hills round here. Also, the Chain Glider needs a reasonably narrow chainring, and the current one is quite fat.

Answer (score 0):

your best option is a Hebie Chainglider. We have it installed on our bike with Alfine, and it works great. If you have Di2 shifting, you need a different back part.